# DatePicker via textField.inputView is shown on the second time only (Regular keyboard is called first time)

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, keyboard

I use four textFields on one page. For the first and second textFields I use regular keyboard.
The third and forth are for time value - I use programmatically created DatePicker and set it via textField.inputView in the IBAction method.

The point is that my DatePicker is shown on the second time only - regular keyboard is called first time instead.

It happens only once - when I open page and click on the text field with time value the very first time. When I tap on this text field second time - it's works fine (my datepicker is shown)

How can I fix that?

The code example:

```
- (IBAction)wakeUpWeekdaysPressed:(id)sender {
    UIDatePicker *timePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;

    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(weekdaysTimePickerDoneAction:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(weekdaysTimePickerCancelAction:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [toolbar setItems:@[cancelButton, flexibleSpace, doneButton]];
    // toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    toolbar.translucent = YES;

    [_wakeUpTimeWeekdays setInputView:timePicker];
    [_wakeUpTimeWeekdays setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue another way.

The DatePicker was being initialized in IBAction method for text field.
The root cause of main issue was that I selected sent event type for method `Editing Did End`. So I changed sent event into `Editing Did Begin`.

Now it works fine. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just write your code in viewdidload instead of this method.

Comment: doesn't help, now either datepicker or keyboard don't show up for this text field

Comment: (IBAction)wakeUpWeekdaysPressed:(id)sender method called on any button click? if yes then dont do like this. paste this code in viewdidload and dont resignfirstresponder.

Comment: there is no need to make IBaction. You can easily do this setup in vieddidload. and that is standard way. If you will follow it, you will not face this kind of problem in future.! I have updated my answer according.

Comment: Thank you. Your option works as well.

The point to keep this code in separate IBAction method is that I need to populate this datePicker with the value from textField. Don't know how to do it yet.